# Sort Related Products By Name | Magento CE

Tags: php, magento, sorting, product

I am attempting to sort related products by name that appear on the product detail page of Magento. There are some hints on how to do this but I cannot transfer this knowledge to the related.phtml page.

The line

```
    foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
```

is where I am stumbling. Within this array $this->getItems() there is an id labeled 'name' that should be sortable.

See http://daniel.gd/how-to-sort-items-in-magentos-cart-page/ and http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/magento-get-items-in-order/

I am stuck at trying to emulate what the person did in the first link, but I cannot find the correct getModel call to use.

I also thought about expanding the array into another one so it could be sorted, then print from that newly sorted array. However this appears to be a bit beyond my coding skills. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a collection design in place. So use collection and apply sorting.

```
getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

is the recommended way.

Make sure  that attribute in question is sortable. The above code is for `name` attribute.